# Flutter: how to set dropdown text with default value and fetch record in datatable according to that value?

Tags: flutter, dropdown

I am displaying records in data table according to the selected month from drop down, but now I want to display default current month in dropdown and display its data in data table. and then user can able to select value from dropdown too.

i am getting record in datatable by using dropdown selected value index, i increment it by 1 as index starts from zero, i mention my this working in code in as add comments where i do what.

here is my code

```
String _selectedMonth;
int monthIndex;
int month;

var monthsList=<String>[
      'January',
      'Febuary',
      'March',
      'April',
      'May',
      'June',
      'July',
      'Augest',
      'September',
      'October',
      'November',
      'December'
  ];

  String getdate="";
    void _getDate() {
    final String formattedDateTime =
        DateFormat('MM').format(DateTime.now()).toString();
    _selectedMonth=DateFormat('MMMM').format(DateTime.now());
    setState(() {
      getdate = formattedDateTime;
      print(currentmonth);
     print("date  "+getdate);
    });
  }
   void initState() {
      _userDetails();
      _getDate();
      _getRecord(); 
  }

 Future<List<History>> _getRecord() async{
   Dio dio=new Dio();
   var data={
     'username':getName,
     'month':month,
     'token':getaccesstoken
   };
   return dio
    .post(localhostUrlAttendanceHistory,data: json.encode(data))
      .then((onResponse) async {
        Map<String, dynamic> map=onResponse.data;     
        List<dynamic> data = map['data'];
 
        for (var h in data) {
          History history = History(
            h["_id"],
            h["Date"], 
            h["TimeIn"], 
            h["TimeOut"],
          );
          historyList.add(history);
          id=history.id.toString();
          print("id is ");
          print(id);
        }
        return historyList;
      })
      .catchError((onerror){
        print(onerror.toString());
       
    });
  }

//datatable code

 Widget attendanceHistory(List<History> 
    historyList)=> 
   Center(
     child:Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 18, 0),
      child:SingleChildScrollView(
         scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
           scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,          
           child:DataTable(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(color: Colors.blue[500], width: 2)),
          headingRowColor: MaterialStateColor.resolveWith((states) => Colors.blue[500]),
          headingTextStyle: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.white),
          showBottomBorder: true,
          headingRowHeight: 60,
          horizontalMargin: 7,
          columnSpacing: 15,      
          dataRowColor: MaterialStateColor.resolveWith((states) => Colors.blue[50]),
          dividerThickness: 4,        
          columns: <DataColumn>[
        DataColumn(label: Text("Date")),
        DataColumn(label: Text("Time in")),
        DataColumn(label: Text("Time out"),numeric: true),
        DataColumn(label: Text("   Edit")),
    ],
    rows:     
    historyList
      ?.map((element)=>DataRow(
        selected: true ,
      cells: <DataCell>[
      DataCell(Text(element?.date),),
      DataCell(Text(element?.timeIn)),
      DataCell(Text(element?.timeOut,)),
      DataCell(IconButton(icon:Icon(Icons.edit,color: Colors.blue,),onPressed: (){
        _getSelectedRowInfo(element?.id,element?.date,element?.timeIn,element?.timeOut);
      })


void _getSelectedRowInfo(dynamic id,dynamic date,dynamic timein,dynamic timeout) {
  
    AlertDialog alert = AlertDialog(  
    scrollable: true, 
    insetPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 50),
    title: Text("Request to change time",style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,color: Colors.blue[500])),  
    
    content:Container(child: SingleChildScrollView( 
      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
    child:Column(children:<Widget> [     
      TextField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: date,hintText: "Date"),
        controller:dateController ,
        
      ),
      TextField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: timein,hintText: "Time in",icon: Icon(Icons.timer)),
        controller:timeinController ,
        readOnly:true,
        onTap: () async {
                  TimeOfDay pickedTime =  await showTimePicker(
                          initialTime: TimeOfDay.now(),
                          context: context,
                      );
        if(pickedTime != null ){
                      print(pickedTime.format(context));   //output 10:51 PM
                      DateTime parsedTime = DateFormat.jm().parse(pickedTime.format(context).toString());
                      //converting to DateTime so that we can further format on different pattern.
                      print(parsedTime); //output 1970-01-01 22:53:00.000
                      String formattedTime = DateFormat('HH:mm:ss').format(parsedTime);
                      print(formattedTime); //output 14:59:00
                      //DateFormat() is from intl package, you can format the time on any pattern you need.

                      setState(() {
                        timeinController.text = formattedTime; //set the value of text field. 
                      });
                  }else{
                      print("Time is not selected");
                  }
                },
      ),
      TextField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(labelText:timeout,hintText: "Time out",icon: Icon(Icons.timer_off)),
        controller:timeoutController ,
        readOnly:true,
        onTap: () async {
                  TimeOfDay pickedTime =  await showTimePicker(
                          initialTime: TimeOfDay.now(),
                          context: context,
                      );
        if(pickedTime != null ){
                      print(pickedTime.format(context));   //output 10:51 PM
                      DateTime parsedTime = DateFormat.jm().parse(pickedTime.format(context).toString());
                      //converting to DateTime so that we can further format on different pattern.
                      print(parsedTime); //output 1970-01-01 22:53:00.000
                      String formattedTime = DateFormat('HH:mm:ss').format(parsedTime);
                      print(formattedTime); //output 14:59:00
                      //DateFormat() is from intl package, you can format the time on any pattern you need.

                      setState(() {
                        timeoutController.text = formattedTime; //set the value of text field. 
                      });
                  }else{
                      print("Time is not selected");
                  }
                },
      ),
      
     ]), 
  )
  
  ),

  actions: [  
      FlatButton(  
    child: Text("Submit",style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,color: Colors.blue[500],fontSize: 20),),  
    onPressed: () { 

    getupdatedTime();
    Dio dio=new Dio();
        var data={
          'id': id,
          'token':getaccesstoken,
          'TimeIn': timeinText,
          'TimeOut':timeoutText,
          
        };
        print("token is "+getaccesstoken);
        print("submit id is  "+id);
        print(data);
        dio
        .put(localhostUrlMarkCorrection, data: json.encode(data))
          .then((onResponse) async {
            Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop('dialog');
            dialoguebox();

            print("mark correction");
            print(onResponse.data);
            print(onResponse.statusCode);
            
            
          }).catchError((onerror){
            print(onerror.toString());
        });
      }
      
    )],  
  );  
      showDialog(  
      context: context,  
      builder: (BuildContext context) {  
        return alert;  
      },  
    );  
      
}


Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: new MyAppBar(title: Text("My Attendance"),onpressed: (){
       Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>Profile()));
   }),
    
    drawer:Emp_DrawerCode(),
   
    body:Stack(children: <Widget>[
//here is my dropdown code
        Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(45, 80, 10, 0),
        child:
        DropdownButton<String>(
        value: _selectedMonth==null?null:monthsList[monthIndex],    
        items: 
          monthsList   
          .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
            return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
              value: value,
              child: Text(value)
            );
          }).toList(),
          hint:Text(
            "Please choose a month",
          ),
          onChanged: (String value) {
            setState(() {
              _selectedMonth=value;  //i am getting month here 
              monthIndex = monthsList.indexOf(value);  //then getting its index, so that i can find month in number
              month=monthIndex+1;  //and as index start from 0 so i increment it by 1
              print(month);
              print(_selectedMonth);
            });
          },
        ),
      ),

class History {
  final String id;
  final String date;
  final String timeIn;
  final String timeOut;
  

  History(this.id,this.date, this.timeIn, this.timeOut);

}
```

please help, if anyone know how to do this.

Comment: Did I understand correctly your question, regarding selecting the default month ?

Comment: @Wapazz I want, when user redirect to this screen, so it will show the current month on dropdown and its data in data table by default, then user can select month too from dropdown and then table will modify according to selected month from dropdown

Comment: So current month is what I suggested in my answer below, and your datatable could be also based on the mothIndex to display the corresponding value.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply get the current month in your initState function and start your index with this number:

(The -1 is because your array starts at 0 and not 1)

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    monthIndex = DateTime.now().month - 1;
    super.initState();
  }
```

This will display the current month by default thanks to `monthIndex`.

Use this variable to display the correct data in your datatable as well.

Comment: My dropdown is default set to current month, but it is not displaying the records in datatable

Comment: can u please help again

Comment: Could you add the datatable code ? How can we help this matter when you only share the dropdown part ?

Comment: I edit my question with code u required, please check it now